# cloud functions only deployment have an issue in the firebase console

Tags: function, deployment, cloud

I am trying to deploy a single and simple functions in the firebase cloud function and it deploy complete in the terminal but there is an issue in the firebase console after running the "firebase deploy --only functions script" it says "function deployment failed. try again" in the firebase console.

I have am trying to delete node_modules and package-lock.json and npm install again and it takes more time to solve but it does not work. anyone would help me appreciated.[this is the image for terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nAB.png)]
[this is the firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvUZA.png)]